# Get data from api by Angular, but no data loaded, what I have to do?

Tags: angular, angular-material

This is the code from the ts file:

```
getroletypes() {
    return this.http
        .get(this.url + "/roletypes")
        .catch((error: any) => {
            return Observable.throw(error.error || "Server error");
        });
}

this.getRoletypes();

roletypes = [];

getRoletypes() {
    this.promotionService.getroletypes().subscribe((response: any) => {
        this.roletypes = response.data;
        this.roletypes.map((item) => {
            item.name = item.name + "=>" + item.id;
        });
    });
}
```

This is the code from the HTML file:

```
 <ng-select
        formControlName="role"
        [items]="roletypes"
        name="id"
        bindLabel="name"
        bindValue="id"
      >
```

Get data from API by Angular but no data loaded what do I have to do?

Comment: The result of your `.map` logic is not being used / assigned to anything.

Comment: see that you use `map(..=>{})` -see the `{` `}`- so you need use "return": `map((item)=>{item.name=item.name+'=>'+item.id;return item}`. You can also use forEach instead map. BTW:check the response using `console.log(response)`

Answer (score 0):

Map needs to return some thing to get assigned,
not sure if this is what you want but try

```js
this.roletypes.map((item) => {
           item.name = item.name + "=>" + item.id;
           return item;
        });
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to tweek the subscribe call. this is the issue. Try to put your response too

Comment: Can you explain me more